# How to remove nf_conntrack module when use dockerd

Tags: docker, iptables

My cluster not use docker0 bridge but ovs bridge. The docker0 bridge start with docker daemon, and the nf_conntrack module load with docker0 bridge start(iptables).

Now I am clearly don't want nf_conntrack module load in docker host, so I think maybe I can stop it with docker network `type = none`.

Unfortunately I d'dn't found any parameters like "`--network=none`" in dockerd, but in "`docker run`".

So is there any way I can remove nf_conntrack module?

PS: rmmod is no use in this case cause those module who depend on nf_conntrack always in use.